# telegram bot with cron and PHP script

Tags: php, cron, telegram-bot

on EC2

I have a crontab like that

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/bot.php
```

The bot.php file

```
  1 <?php
  2 
  3 exec( 'touch /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/testCron.txt');
  4 
  5   $botToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  6 
  7   $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
  8   $chatId=123456;  
  9   $params=[
 10       'chat_id'=>$chatId,
 11       'text'=>'test bitnami',
 12   ];
 13   $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
 14   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 15   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 16   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 17   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
 18   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 19   $result = curl_exec($ch);
 20
 21   if ($result === FALSE) {
 22      echo 'An error has occured: ' . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL;
 23   }
 24   else {
 25      echo $result;
 26   }
 27 
 28   curl_close($ch);
 29 
 30 ?>
```

testCron.txt is created so the cronTab works.

When I open bot.php with firefox the API call works and the bot sent the message on Telegram, but the PHP script with curl doesn't work with Cron.

I put htdocs and bot.php permissions to 777 for testing and it didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint: I'm adding it as an answer since my reputation (as of now) is below 50.*

As of now I would need more information in order to support. There might be multiple potential issues here. Let's see if we can go down the road together.

**1. Make errors visible during cron execution**

In this case you could check your logs inside your cron. I would suggest to log any output into a file by the this to your cron  `>> /var/log/my-cron.log 2>&1`.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/bot.php >> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/testCron.log 2>&1
```

From here on we can check if there is any execution errors, permission errors or some misconfiguration.

**2. Check your error-log configuration**

It might be that your errors are not displayed. Here is a good starting point for some configuration

```
// tells your script to report any error
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

// tells your script to enable error logging and the location where it should log to
ini_set('log_errors', '1'); // tells your script to enable logging
ini_set('error_log', '/dev/stderr');
```

Let's see if this is enough to get an initial idea or if we need to dig deeper.

Comment: I edit bot.php to display the curl output. When I open the file from browser everything looks ok :

{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":64,"from":{"id":....
        
cron logs:
(bitnami) CMD (/usr/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/bot.php)          
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
       
When I run curl from terminal it works.
      
Actually the PHP script just didn't work when it's run by crontab (just the curl part, the first part with touch command works).

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, i would suggest you put this as a comment since you are asking for more clarification  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa I am only allowed to add comments with a reputation of 50+ otherwise I would have put it in a comment.

Comment: okay, i would suggest you edit the answer to remove the questions and add suggestive answer, it doesn't have to be perfect

Comment: @JonatanBuzek since you do not see potential error output `(..., discarding output)`. Could you redirect the output to a file by using this `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/bot.php > /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/testCron.log 2>&1`

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa thank your for the hint! I have adopted my answer according to that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I follow your instructions and directly saw the problem:
In testCron.log:  **undefined function  curl_init()**  
I solved this by installing the Curl extension for PHP 
**sudo apt install php-curl**
But I don't understand why it worked with the browser directly if the extension was missing.

Comment: @JonatanBuzek glad I could help :)