# Cronjob not running php script

Tags: php, cron

I've done some searching before this post and I still can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to setup a cron job with PHPMailer to send out an email every so often. The script below does work if I run it manually but does not work in the cron job scheduler.

For this example - I set it to run every minute. I'm thinking it has to do something with the "vendor/autoload.php" and it's path not loading correctly? I didn't add my SMTP credentials with api key for security reasons as well as recipients for this post.

**Here is my cron job setup in Cpanel.**
[image]

**Here is my PHPMailer code**:

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    // Server settings
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                   // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '';                               // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';   // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    // Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('email@email.com', '');
    $mail->addAddress('email@email.com', '');                      // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('email@email.com', '');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                        // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer email';
    // $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('email.html'), __DIR__); // Use this if not using the above code

    // ********* PHP-MAILER ********* //


    $mail->send();
    echo 'Email sent!';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share you error-message with us? I assume this will help a lot to find the issue.

I've shared my insights how to enable logging in a different post on stack overflow (see link below). This will explain how you can display errors in your cron execution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250715/12880865

Please let me know if this helps you. If you'll get a proper error message, please share it with us so we can dig further into your question.

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment as it doesn't provide a solution to the isse.

Comment: Thank you Christoph! Great idea. I will look over your post in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: @Christoph Kluge it didn't get my final answer but it helped me get there so thank you!

Comment: @code glad that it helped. Just out of curiosity. Do you want to share what error you had after checking the error-message? Missing php package installed? Missing dependency? Permission errors?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I had to use [(dirname(**DIR**)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) which is the directory of the file.

**I Changed:**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

**to:**

```
require (dirname(__DIR__).'/mailer/vendor/autoload.php');
```